# An object with an undefined `constructor` property

Tags: javascript

So I have an object created by the `eventemitter3` node module. The event emitter has a property `_events`, which, when I look at it in the Chrome inspector, shows `Events {}`. However, when I attempt to look at its constructor (`temp1.constructor`), I get `undefined`! Under the description on MDN ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)), it says "All objects will have a `constructor` property", yet I have a clear counterexample here in my Chrome console (I also tried this in Firefox, so it's unlikely to be a problem with V8).

I can see in [the eventemitter3 source](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3/blob/master/index.js) the following lines that define the `Events` class:

```
//
// We try to not inherit from `Object.prototype`. In some engines creating an
// instance in this way is faster than calling `Object.create(null)` directly.
// If `Object.create(null)` is not supported we prefix the event names with a
// character to make sure that the built-in object properties are not
// overridden or used as an attack vector.
//
if (Object.create) {
  Events.prototype = Object.create(null);

  //
  // This hack is needed because the `__proto__` property is still inherited in
  // some old browsers like Android 4, iPhone 5.1, Opera 11 and Safari 5.
  //
  if (!new Events().__proto__) prefix = false;
}
```

So I suppose it makes sense that they're trying to get rid of the `constructor` property but:

1. How does Chrome still know where the object came from enough to print its name in the console?
2. Is the MDN description wrong about constructors?
3. How can I glean the string `"Events"` from the object in JavaScript?

Comment: What is the difference between `temp1` and `_events`? You just confused me.  Because _its constructor_ would be found here  `_events.constructor`

Comment: The MDN description is misleading. By "all objects" they mean "all normal objects", as `Object.create(null)` is a very specific exception in that it creates objects that do not inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: `_events` is a property on the object, not a standalone variable. I right-click => Store as Global Variable to set it to `window.temp1`. Storing the full `EventEmitter` as `e` and trying `e._events.constructor` yields the same result.

Comment: Chrome probably adds a hidden property to the object when you construct it with `new`.